# How to compensate for font sizes when switching fonts

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

Say you have a Web page which:

1. Uses a single font: `* { font-family: SomeFont }`
2. The style sheet is huge and made by **someone else**, so you don't know it in detail
3. Font sizes may be set using any known technique (`px`, `em`, `rem`, `ex`, `%`, etc.)

When you change the font to `* { font-family: NewFont }`, the new font appears 20% larger than the original, breaking a lot of layout.

Evidently, there is some inconsistency in the actual size of different fonts, so you can't just switch fonts and expect the new font to stay without the boundaries of another font.

Is there a simple way to compensate for this without having to manually set new font sizes for all tags, using only a single statement of pure CSS, something like `body { font-size: 80% }`.